# Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue. Aborted due to warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

here is my gruntfile.js

```js
var fs = require("fs"),
    browserify = require("browserify"),
    pkg = require("./package.json");

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    mochaTest: {
      test: {
        options: {
          style: 'bdd',
          reporter: 'spec'
        },
        src: ['test/unit/*.js']
      }
    },
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: "/*\n" + grunt.file.read('LICENSE') + "*/"
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%=pkg.name%>-<%=pkg.version%>.min.js': ['<%=pkg.name%>-<%=pkg.version%>.js']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', 'build a browser file', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    var outfile = './brain-' + pkg.version + '.js';

    var bundle = browserify('./browser.js').bundle(function(err, src) {
      console.log("> " + outfile);

      // prepend license
      var license = fs.readFileSync("./LICENSE");
      src = "/*\n" + license + "*/" + src;

      // write out the browser file
      fs.writeFileSync(outfile, src);
      done();
    });
  });
  grunt.registerTask('test', 'mochaTest');

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
};
```

When I simply run grunt in the terminal - here is the error

**Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.**

After adding --force it shows:

**Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.
Done, but with warnings.**

Comment: You have to register a task called "default". Without registering it, grunt doesn't know what all tasks to execute (by default) when "grunt" command is executed.

Comment: Thanks buddy. But I'm newbie, can you please show me how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand how grunt command work

1. you define/register a task in your Gruntfile.js
2. Thenyou call that task from the command prompt

From your grunt file below is a task registered

```
 grunt.registerTask('build', 'build a browser file', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    var outfile = './brain-' + pkg.version + '.js';

    var bundle = browserify('./browser.js').bundle(function(err, src) {
      console.log("> " + outfile);

      // prepend license
      var license = fs.readFileSync("./LICENSE");
      src = "/*\n" + license + "*/" + src;

      // write out the browser file
      fs.writeFileSync(outfile, src);
      done();
    });
  });
```

you can then call that task by calling `grunt build` which will run that task. And when you only run `grunt` it looks for a task which name is `default`

As in your grunt file there is no default task defined you command fails.

Comment: Thanks, good explaination. I add default instead of build now it runs from only grunt command but after running how can i open it in browser.

Comment: Write a task which will do so. find and grunt static server which will run your code in browser

Comment: in last portion of code it shows, // write out the browser file. Can you tell me it'll run code in browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is no task called "default" in your gruntfile. Are you trying to run the build task ?

If so, replace this line:

`grunt.registerTask('build', 'build a browser file', function() {
...`

With this line

`grunt.registerTask('default', 'build a browser file', function() {
...`

Comment: Running "default" task
> ./brain-0.7.0.js

Done, without errors.

Thanks but how can i open this from my browser now.

Answer (score 0):

**Tasks have to be registered in grunt before they can be executed**.

You have registered a build task in your grunt,

```
grunt.registerTask('build', 'build a browser file', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    var outfile = './brain-' + pkg.version + '.js';

    var bundle = browserify('./browser.js').bundle(function(err, src) {
      console.log("> " + outfile);

      // prepend license
      var license = fs.readFileSync("./LICENSE");
      src = "/*\n" + license + "*/" + src;

      // write out the browser file
      fs.writeFileSync(outfile, src);
      done();
    });
  });
```

This can be executed by called `grunt build`.

When you execute `grunt`, by default, it looks for a task called `default`, which should be registered.

So, register a `default` task (same like build task)

```
grunt.registerTask('default', 'Executed default task', function() {
    ...
});
```

You can also pass the third parameter as array of registered tasks so that that will be executed if you run `grunt`.

```
grunt.registerTask('default', 'Executed default task', [
    'task1',
    'task4',
    'task3',
]);
```

Now when you execute `grunt`, all these tasks will be executed in sequence.

Please note that the each task in the tasks array should be **registered** using `grunt.registerTask`.

Comment: Thanks. Where will i add port number for local server to reach in my gruntfile?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get it. Why do you want your local server to reach grunt file?

Comment: I want to run my app in browser, where will i add port number so that i can reach it from my browser?

Comment: You can look at [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect). Create a task `server` which will be called after `build` task. Update your `default` task like `grunt.registerTask('default', '<DESCRIPTION>', ['build', 'server']);`

Comment: i installed grunt-contrib-connect and then i update current grunt.registerTask function with your code. But i think It needs port number to add for reaching in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add default task.

add following line after "grunt.registerTask('test', 'mochaTest');" line.

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['test', 'build']);
```

this task will run both 'test' and 'build'. when run "grunt" without any argument.

For more details refer [grunt document on task](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task).

Comment: Thanks but how i can run this in browser as there is no port number mentioned in gruntfile. Sorry if I'm not making sense as I'm new to grunt.

Comment: you are using  [grunt-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-serve). It will serve the file for you. It is default port it "9000"

Comment: yes but it'll be after run this not build. I can use build and it works but how can i run it so that i can access it at port 9000.
I can't reach it on 9000 after using grunt build command.

Comment: add "grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-serve');" to Gruntfile.js and run "grunt serve". Will it helps?

Comment: no, actually i find that here grunt-contrib-connect this is used.